# numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square in np.dot

Tags: python, numpy

```
A = np.array([[2,-1],[-1,2],[0,-1]])
q, r = np.linalg.qr(A, 'complete')

print(q)
print(r)

# The line below will raise error: numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
print(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(r), q.T))
# Mathmatically, I think it should output something similar to the following code, if im not wrong. The following code should be able to run
print(np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T, A)), A.T))
```

I was trying to get this piece of code to work, but is getting this error:

> numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be
> square

I know the second matrix is not square, but is there anyway that I can make this code to work? For example, is there a way to by pass this or to change the matrix to square?

Comment: Tell us about `r`.  Focus on what `np.linalg.inv` and `qr`  document.

Comment: Discarding the final row of zeros will let you compute `np.linalg.inv(r[:2, :])`

Comment: `A` is (3,2).  According to the docs, `qr` with `complete`, returns an `r` with the same shape.    Why do you expect to do `inv` on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [117]: q
Out[117]: 
array([[-0.89442719, -0.35856858,  0.26726124],
       [ 0.4472136 , -0.71713717,  0.53452248],
       [-0.        ,  0.5976143 ,  0.80178373]])

In [118]: r        # same shape as A, (3,2) as per docs
Out[118]: 
array([[-2.23606798,  1.78885438],
       [ 0.        , -1.67332005],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

`r` without the 0's row is invertable:

```
In [120]: np.linalg.inv(r[:2])
Out[120]: 
array([[-0.4472136 , -0.47809144],
       [-0.        , -0.5976143 ]])
```

We can `dot` it with a part of `q`:

```
In [130]: np.dot(np.linalg.inv(r[:2]),q.T[:2])
Out[130]: 
array([[ 0.57142857,  0.14285714, -0.28571429],
       [ 0.21428571,  0.42857143, -0.35714286]])
```

Which does match:

```
In [131]: np.dot(np.linalg.inv(np.dot(A.T, A)), A.T)
Out[131]: 
array([[ 0.57142857,  0.14285714, -0.28571429],
       [ 0.21428571,  0.42857143, -0.35714286]])
```

### pinv

```
In [5]: np.linalg.pinv(r)
Out[5]: 
array([[-0.4472136 , -0.47809144,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.5976143 ,  0.        ]])

In [6]: np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(r),q.T)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0.57142857,  0.14285714, -0.28571429],
       [ 0.21428571,  0.42857143, -0.35714286]])
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry for the late reply, Actually I just learned that linalg.pinv can do the pseudo inversion for the rectangular matrices, which should solve this problem in a generic way. Thanks a lot for you reply, really appreciated it!